# Why do professors use reverse trick questions (questions that are seemingly difficult but actually easy?)

Tags: exams

Often, on exams in particular, *reverse trick questions* are posed. These are questions which look tough, complex, and pompous, but are actually easy and can be solved by applying some basic method. I give an example later.

Why are these used by professors?

I think they are very inappropiate, since they put the smart student at a disadvantage, and the less smart at an advantage. If you ask a question which is designed to seem difficult, the smart student mentally approaches the problem as a difficult problem, and therefore gets ready to use the more complicated tools at their disposal. Thus, one might be working for a considerable time trying to apply a complicated technique on a problem, which could be solved in seconds if one spotted the easy 'hidden' method. This is in particular a problem on exams and tests, where time is an important factor.

Meanwhile, the less smart and stupid students approach the problem as they approach any other: "*well, here's a problem which concerns topic A, I only know that one basic easy method regarding topic A which they taught the first day, so might as well apply it and see where it gets me even though it seems unlikely to work, whoops, it actually did work!*", and they might be done with the problem immediately.

So, what do you think?

---

Here's an example of math. I was once asked to take the integral of a very ugly looking function, it was a fraction, with both numerator and denominator looking like the spawn of the devil.

I spent some time trying to simplify it, so that I might get an idea of what sort of method would work best. I already disregarded integration by parts, since it was obvious that it would lead to many complicated terms that I wouldn't want to bother with. Ultimately, this did not work.

Turns out, the actual solution is to not simplify it, not look for an appropiate method, but just blindly apply integration by parts to the expression in its original form. This method, by design, leads to many complicated terms disappearing and making the integral way easier to solve (something which was impossible to predict). This was of course intentional by the professor.

I think this is a question which smart students will take longer to solve (since they know more methods and are better at creative simplification), while less smart students will solve immediately (since their first and only thought will be to just apply integration by parts).

Comment: _and the less smart at an advantage_ -- I don't buy this, and this is a big [citation needed] red flag for me.

Comment: This seems to be a case of extrapolating one's own personal disappointment into some overly sweeping rationalization

Comment: if you *were* smart, then you would not have discarded integration by parts without even trying.

Comment: @MadJack I think the scenario that OP is describing is very real, although I take issue with their "smart" and "stupid" terminology, as I explained in my answer. A citation may be needed, and may be hard or impossible to come by, but I do "buy this" and suggest that you reconsider your objection. See my answer for more thoughts on this.

Comment: Probably the professor thinks it's a cute question, and decided to do one final example of integration by parts before you guys forget what it is.  You shouldn't blame the professor for 'over thinking' a question.

Comment: @DanRomik OP's claim doesn't sync up with my experience, which is: on average, the "not-so-smart" students are the ones that spin their wheels and get sidetracked on a lengthy solution attempt, not the "smart" ones.

Comment: There is some use of learning "When you hear hoofbeats, think of horses not zebras."

Comment: _I think they are very inappropiate, since they put the smart student at a disadvantage, and the less smart at an advantage._ — And I think they're perfectly appropriate, for exactly the same reason.  I don't care how smart you are.  I want to know if you can do the work.  If trying to be clever gets in the way of doing the work, then trying to be clever should be penalized.

Comment: Real life often hands out questions that look difficult but are really easy seen the right way. It is important to learn to look at multiple approaches, not just lock in on one way that one uses wherever possible.

Answer (score 12):

> Often, on exams in particular, reverse trick questions are posed. These are questions which look tough, complex, and pompous, but are actually easy and can be solved by applying some basic method. ... Why are these used by professors?

I think that's a really interesting question, and I recognize the existence of such questions and the phenomenon of stronger students having a harder time solving certain kinds of questions than less strong students. Let me try to offer a sort of explanation.

First of all, the answer to any question of the type "why do professors ask questions [*of some category X*] on exams" would generally be "because they think that such questions are a good way to test students' knowledge and/or think that practicing solving such questions is a good way for their students to develop good skills and habits". Basically professors use exam questions as a way of signaling to their students what the professor considers important, and as a way of imparting subtle pedagogical lessons about the material that are hard to convey effectively in a less hands-on manner. A good question can often be used as a powerful [teachable moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teachable_moment).

So, given the above observation, it makes sense to ask what is it about the sort of "reverse trick questions" (I like that phrase!) you describe that makes (some, not all) professors think such questions offer good teachable lessons. My theory is that such questions offer the lesson that fancy problem-solving tools -- the kind of tools that "smart" students tend to have better mastery of than "non-smart" students -- are not always superior to simpler, more simple-minded tools. Thus, a good "reverse trick question" is a question that illustrates the principle that in problem-solving (in the context of math at least, but also in other STEM areas) one should start applying the techniques one knows starting from the simplest one and in the order of increasing complexity. This can be a counterintuitive lesson to the "smart" students who often get so excited about the fanciest techniques they learn that they are eager to try applying them whenever possible without trying simpler methods first. It is also a valuable lesson that most serious mathematicians eventually learn at some point during their training. (I myself remember seeing this illustrated nicely one time when I was in college, when I solved the classical math puzzle asking at what earliest time after midnight the two dials of a clock point in the same direction by summing an infinite geometric series; the friend who asked me the question thought it was hilarious that I'd used such a sophisticated method rather than the more obvious, much simpler one of solving a linear equation.)

Finally, I should add that I kind of disagree with your characterization of the students who have a hard time with reverse trick question as the "smart" students and with the other ones as being "less smart" or "stupid". In my opinion, part of being "smart" means having an intuitive feel for which techniques to use when attacking a problem, so actually the students who have a good grasp of advanced techniques but have a poor sense of when to try applying them are arguably less "smart" than some other students who know fewer techniques but have a better intuitive feel for effective problem-solving. In other words, being "smart" involves a combination of different skills, and different students are good at each of those different skills to varying extents; **"smartness" is a multi-dimensional quantity and not a linear spectrum**. The TL;DR answer to your question is therefore: **professors try to design exams questions that develop (*all kinds of*) smartness in their students, and "reverse trick questions" may be one way of doing that**.

Comment: Lesson of the day: _Work smarter, not harder_, or _90% inspiration, 10% perspiration_.

Answer (score 6):

The specific question you have in hand (which we don't see...) may indeed have been awkward or clumsy, or misguided, ... However, I can understand that teachers might ask a question whose resolution involves *not* thinking too much about it, but just doing the usual thing. Thus, demonstrating that "the usual thing" is indeed an appropriate approach to many questions, whence its "usualness".

The notion that "smart students will take longer to solve" is plausible, but in the end not supportable, I think, even if the question is clumsy. One hazard of a naive "smartness" is to be drawn into a fantasy world where (supposedly) strange arcane laws hold sway, etc. But, my point would be, even when people *try* to make things arcane, there is (thank heavens) a sort of irresistible underlying mathematical reality which is, to a great degree, immune to tomfoolery. (Not enough to make all grading systems be sane, but that is not mathematics...)

Btw, integration by parts is on my short list... :)

Answer (score 2):

One reason might be exactly what you are saying:

*I think they are very inappropiate, since they put the smart student at a disadvantage, and the less smart at an advantage.*

Probably professors have enough smart students not to worry about the less smart, and instead try to find those smart enough to realize what questions are easy and which aren't without being given explicit clues in the wording of the questions. That is, very smart students (or students who know the topic very well) will know whether a question is easy or not. And anyone who qualifies for studying in college should qualify as *smart* already.